# Salesforce leads from a campaign

Tags: c#, salesforce

What is the most efficient way to get a list of all leads that originated or are associated with a campaign using SOQL? I'm new to SOQL and still having trouble bridging the gap between it and SQL. I can get a list of individual Lead ID's using this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT LeadId FROM CampaignMembers) FROM Campaign
```

But then do I really have to loop through the QueryResult and using queryMore and individually construct each lead? Or is there a simple way to just get a list? There must be as sf does it in the UI.

Sorry if this is a newb question! Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use this list in another application, or do you just want the list of leads?  If it's the latter, then there shouldn't be a problem obtaining the list from a Report in the Org.

Comment: Looking to use it through the API, not through the sf.com UI.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I think you are on the right path with your query above, as long as you know the ID of the Campaign.  Campaign Members are related to a Lead/Contact and a Campaign.  So, the query may be:

Comment: I am having trouble importing both contacts and leads from salesforce. I only get contacts but not leads. What should i do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599195/i-cant-export-contacts-and-leads-both-from-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

As you've stated, you've got all of the leads IDs, now you can just use that list of IDs in a second query to grab the rest of the details you need:

```
select Id, Name, etc... from Lead where Id in ('firstid', 'secondid', 'etc. id')
```

That will return the list of lead objects in question.

Comment: I am having trouble importing both contacts and leads from salesforce. I only get contacts but not leads. What should i do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599195/i-cant-export-contacts-and-leads-both-from-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
select campaignid, campaign.name, leadid, lead.name from campaignmember where leadid != null
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best:

```
SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM CampaignMembers WHERE CampaignMemberId = 'id' LIMIT 200
```